# Why we should not use Bower but Yarn, while both download different codes for the same package?

Tags: bower, babeljs, yarnpkg

For example:

```
yarn add babel
bower install babel
```

I have application running without server (I don't plan to use NodeJS as my back-end). It is now pure-front-end double-click HTML file.

I tried to import browser.js into my HTML file to be able to process JSX.

- Import with `<script src="node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/browser.js">` does not work.
- But, import with `<script src="bower_components/babel/browser.js">` **works**.

Apparently, the codes are different. Since, Bower is dead and it suggests its users to use Yarn, how can the codes be different?

How can I use Yarn like I use Bower?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested. There is no way ReactJS downloaded from package manager like Yarn or NPM work without server. At least any static-file server works.

In my case I ran `yarn build`, go to build directory, make sure the working directory is in the build folder, then run any server from there (root must be at the build folder). I use `python3 -m http.server` (because that is the only thing I conveniently use). I suppose you can use basic NodeJS HTTP as well.

I am not happy with the result, with fact that I can use CDN and Bower to serve React application as a single HTML file but I cannot do as such with  React downloaded form the currently hip package manager.